# "post-name" Renders Using page.php, but "post-name-2" renders with single.php

Tags: permalinks, page-template, single

[Page One](http://www.motherearthnewsfair.com/claudia-lucero/) is rendering using my page.php template.

[Page Two](http://www.motherearthnewsfair.com/claudia-lucero-2/), set up exactly the same as the previous one, is rendering using my single.php template.

I want Page One to render using the single.php template. It's not a custom post type; I've re-saved permalinks; I've done the `flush_rewrite_rules()` after creating the one custom post type I use; and I'm still lost!

Can anybody tell me why adding the "-2" to the slug makes this work?!?!!?

Comment: Somehow one is set up as a post and one is set up as a page. Did you create them both as posts?

Comment: Yep. Set them both up exactly the same. Posts > Add New

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to your admin, I'd have to assume you have a page with the slug "claudia-lucero" - in addition to your post.

Comment: here's page's ID - 705.. in body you have classes: `attachment page page-id-705 page-template-default`.. attachment says that it should be attachment page, but page says that it is pages page.. something definatly wrong here..